# Select from table where id is not in another

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to select all the planes that aren't belong to a certain company. I have three tables in this case: `Planes`, `Companies`, and `CompanyPlanes`.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT *
FROM planes p,
     companyplanes cp,
     companies c
WHERE c.id = ?
  AND cp.idCompany != c.id
  AND (cp.idPlane = p.id OR p.id NOT IN (SELECT idPlane FROM companyplanes)) 
ORDER BY name ASC
```

But this query returned nothing! what is the wrong here?

example:

```
| Plane |
---------
id | name
---------
1  | p1
2  | p2
3  | p3


|Company|
---------
id | name
---------
1  | c1
2  | c2

|     companyPlanes    |
------------------------
id | idCompany | idPlane
------------------------
1  |      1    |    1
2  |      1    |    2
3  |      2    |    2
```

if I want to get the planes that are not belong to the company `c2` the result should be: p1, p3.

Comment: Try `...OR p.id NOT IN (SELECT idPlane FROM companyplanes where idPlane IS NOT NULL)...`.

Comment: @jarlh the same result, null.

Comment: Add some sample table data, and the expected result!

Comment: @jarlh I have added an example

Comment: @Mohammad, Same Plane under two Companies, any typos there?

Comment: @jarlh no, its possible, which is mean that c1 company has a plane of type p2, and also the c2 company has a plane of the same type.

Comment: @Mohammad, Now you check the updated Answer. You will get the expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update Answer**

We can get the result in following way

1. Get all planes of the unexpected company

   `SELECT idplane from CompanyPlanes
   WHERE idCompany = ?`
2. Get all planes without those planes of the unexpected company

   `SELECT * FROM Planes
   WHERE id NOT IN
      (
         SELECT idplane from CompanyPlanes
         WHERE idCompany = ?
      )`

You don't need to `join` with `Company` table as you already get `idCompany` from `CompanyPlanes` table.

Comment: thank you, so simple, but the condition should be `WHERE idCompany = ?` instead of `WHERE idCompany != ?`

Answer (score 0):

The inner join requires that the query return rows from planes which have a corresponding row in companyplanes but the subselect excludes any rows which have corresponding records in companyplanes.

Assuming that you want the records from planes which don't have a record in companyplanes, then why are you also selecting from companies?

```
Select p.*
From planes p
Left join
  Companyplanes do
On p.id=cp.idplane
Where cp.idplane is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question the right way, this is what you might be looking for..

```
select p.*
from planes p 
     join companyplanes cp on cp.idPlane=p.id
     join companies c on c.id=cp.idCompany
where c.id != ?
```